# Gritty Buttermilk Gravy

Tags: buttermilk, gravy

I make gravy at the restaurant where I work. One week, I made a great buttermilk brown gravy. The next week, I tried to replicate it and the end product was very gritty and grainy. Does anyone have any insight into why this happened? I added it with my other liquid (heavy cream) after I browned my roux.

I know I can make smooth buttermilk gravy, I just don't know what caused it to get gritty like that. Thanks!

I use 2 pounds of flour, 2 pounds of butter, 1.5 gallons of cream, and 1.5 gallons of buttermilk.

I make a brown roux, add onions, let them caramelize, then I start adding warm milk and room temperature buttermilk. I let it sit on the burner to heat up and thicken. It will get less gritty as it thickens but the grittiness never went away the second time.

Edit: Added more clarity to process.

Comment: What ingredients and process did you use?

Comment: @Catija I edited my post with more information.

Comment: One possibility is that second time, you added the liquids (mik and buttermilk) faster. if you are whisking and adding milk, if you add too fast, the base roux may separate into tiny parts and "float" in the milk rather than incorporate the milk onto itself. The first quart of liquid would be most crucial for this i.e. you would need to add them slowly and make sure the liquid expands the roux instead of separating from roux.

Comment: related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/why-is-my-cheese-sauce-gritty

Comment: Boiling too long/hard (full rolling boil as opposed to a slow simmer) can also cause the roux to break down and go gritty.  Perhaps the heat was too high the second time?

Comment: Yeah, I would guess too much heat and not enough whisking.